# Ruby Siren jsonquery

Tags: ruby, siren

My json content stored in a file:

```
{
    "vms": [
        {
            "component": "pgdb",
            "count": "1",
            "endpoints": "80:8080,5432:5432"
        },
        {
            "component": "mq",
            "count": "1",
            "endpoints": "80:8080,5672:5672,15672:15672"
        },
        {
            "component": "ucms",
            "count": "1",
            "endpoints": "80:80,8080:8080"
        },
        {
            "component": "wsgw",
            "count": "1",
            "endpoints": "8080:8080,9093:9093"
        }
    ]
}

in irb :

require 'json'
require 'Siren'

json = File.read('c:\\stack1.json')
irb(main):022:0> Siren.query "$.vms..[? @.component == ucms ]", json
=> []
```

I am trying to draft a query that will search on component name and return the value of endpoints.
Any help/pointers will be appreciated.

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

For string matching you need to use `=` operator, instead of `==`. Also the file read needs to be parsed before the query:

```
json = Siren.parse File.read('c:\\stack1.json')
Siren.query "$.vms..[? @.component = ucms ]", json
```

Comment: Thanx Edu, that helps. Sorry cannot upvote your answer as I dont have enough reputation.